# saveorupdate call in Junit test case throws no transaction in progress error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

**Premise**

I have a Spring 5.1.5 project with Hibernate 5.4.1

The compilation goes through fine but while running test cases for a particular package I see multiple tests failing. All with the same error:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress at com.project.server.package.dao.impl.SomeDAOImplTest.someTest(SomeDAOImplTest.java:54)

**The Problem**

Now I know that Hibernate 5 enforces the check for a transaction and it doesn't find one here and throws an exception. My question is why does it do that given I have transactions initialized via spring context.

My test case:

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:/spring/applicationContext-package-dao--test.xml" })
public class SomeDAOImplTest extends AbstractDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeDAO someDAO;
    private className obj;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        obj = new ClassName();
        obj.setId(3);

        someDAO.saveOrUpdate(obj);
    }
```

My `applicationContext-package-dao--test.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:/spring/applicationContext-persistence-datasource-test.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/spring/applicationContext-package-dao.xml" />

</beans>
```

The imported context `applicationContext-persistence-datasource-test.xml` has a bean `txProxyTemplate` as below:

```
<beans>
.
.//other beans
.
<bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="com.desktone.transaction.DtResourcelessTransactionManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
.
.//other beans
.
</beans>
```

The other `applicationContext-package-dao.xml` has the bean definition for `SomeDAO` which has `txProxyTemplate` as it's parent.

```
<bean id="SomeDAO" parent="txProxyTemplate">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="com.project.server.package.dao.impl.SomeDAOImpl">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="saveOrUpdate">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                <prop key="delete">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

The saveorupdate call from `SomeDAOImplTest` calls `SomeDAOImpl` whose spring context config is `applicationContext-package-dao.xml` and has the Hibernate `saveorupdate()` call.

**Things I have Tried:**

- Manually adding @Transactional tag to SomeDAOImplTest. (still throws no tx error)
- Experimenting with PROPAGATION.REQUIRES_NEW (still throws no tx error) & PROPAGATION.MANDATORY(says marked mandatory but no tx).
- Made sure the autowire is initialzing the bean.

**Primary Suspicion**

I suspect somehow the `someDAO` bean is initialized but `txProxyTemplate` bean isn't, so no `transactionManager` is in place. However, I have found no clues to coroborate this.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was happening because of a very fundamental issue. I'll explain the issue and the fix will be intuitive to everyone afterward.

When a Spring application runs all the beans are loaded in a single/global context. So even if some spring bean configuration depends on a transaction bean(for me it was `txProxyTemplate`) which isn't present in the same package at runtime it will be able to access it.

However, that's not true for a test case. My tests were reporting no transaction in progress since they couldn't load the `txProxyTemplate` and actually start a transaction. So my tests never ran in a transaction and I didn't know any better until I upgraded to Hibernate 5 and they put a hard constraint on this.

As you might have guessed defining the `txProxyTemplate` in the same spring config helped me work past this issue.

Good learning.